# jenkins plugin to display summary of builds for the day

Tags: plugins, build, continuous-integration, jenkins

Is there a plugin for jenkins that reports on the summary of the results of the build for the day?

e.g. a job executes 10 times a day and at the end of the day it will report on the results of all the builds.

Answer (score 6):

Depending how much customization you need you may find [Radiator View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Radiator+View+Plugin) or [eXtreme Feedback Panel Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/eXtreme+Feedback+Panel+Plugin) useful.

You can also write your own custom Groovy-based job that utilizes [Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) to access [Jenkins API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/) in order to collect and display the statistics you need.